# Should Software Testing really become a first-class concept at the academic level?

Tags: unit-testing

Is Software Testing really given its importance at the academic level?

I believe there is a need in universities offering Software Engineering (and probably even Computer Science) to treat **Software Testing** as a separate course and topic in itself, rather than as part of a general topic of Software Engineering. Irrespective of the testing methodology and techninque used, this is something that is as much a part of a software professional's life as writing code.

I am not sure this is happening in most of universities - it is still being given secondary importance. When a fresh graduate comes out of university, he is all about programming and creating things, not on how to test them.

Should Software Testing really become a first-class concept at the academic level (or at-least treated like one)?

Comment: The question in your title and the question at the end of your post are asking opposite things. If I said "yes", it wouldn't be clear.

Comment: @Ather--this strikes me as a broad and open-ended question.  For example, how many college SE programs have you looked at?  Are you sure that most of them have no offerings in Software Testing?  It seems to me that you're making some possibly unjustified generalizations.  Downvoted.

Comment: I have yet to interview a CS grad out of college who has any idea what testing involves.

Comment: @cfeduke--For that matter, I know working professionals who have no clue with regards to software testing so I'm not sure all the blame for this can be laid at the feet of academia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it probably should be given more consideration, and at some places it is.  As a part of the new curriculum at the university I attended all programming projects are required to include test cases.  There's no way to enforce a particular methodology, like TDD, but I think this is a step in the right direction.

There are even tools available, like [Web-CAT](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1384371), that allow for automated evaluation of test coverage.  The students submit their code and their tests, and the system tells them how they scored against a set of instructor-accepted tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

At my university it was given equal theoretical coverage as software requirements and software development.  All 3 had a third-level course mandatory for SE and optional for CS.  Even though many courses require programming most courses aren't actually *about* programming.

Comment: What University did you attend?

Answer (score 0):

I believe unit testing should be taught at the academic level, but not testing in general.  A software tester need not worry him/herself with the same level of technical detail as the developer, meaning a broader understanding would probably be sufficient.